# Convert int to Calendar Object

Tags: java, android

I am working in a Calendar Project and using this Github project:
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

I got the calendar working but my requirement is to disable all the weekdays and enable only Saturday and Sunday.

The library has a functionality as `datepickerdialog.setDisabledDays()` in which we have to pass the `Calendar[]`.

If I add `Calendar.Monday` to the array (which returns `int` value), it throws an error like

```
setDisabledDays (java.util.Calendar[]) in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied to (int)
```

What I basically try to do is, to add all the weekdays in a `Calendar` array to disable them. So, how to convert `int` value to `Calendar` in Java?

Comment: It doesn’t look easy from skimming over the page you are linking to. I gather you would have to explicitly enable every Saturday and Sunday in the calendar period you could imagine your user would choose from.

Comment: Yes @OleV.V. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Still i don't find the way to disable the weekdays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes @OleV.V. Any idea on how to do it?

Yes and no. I would use `ZonedDateTime` for the calculations, and this is not readily available in your Android Java 7. If you are going to do more work with dates and/or times in your app and/or you foresee maintaining it for the years to come, you should consider using the ThreeTen ABP library. This gives you the date and time classes described in JSR-310. These are the ones to use for dates and times in 2017. Also because Stack Overflow is supposed to be a knowledge base, I will present this option first and the one without JSR-310 afterwards.

You asked about what to pass to `setDisabledDays()`. As I read your link, you would need to pass an array containing all the days that the user is not allowed to pick. In principle that’s infinitely many days. So you first need to decide how far into the past and/or the future the user really needs to select a day. Then force the user within your limit so you can control the pick. Next I think that it’s much easier to control it through `setSelectableDays`. This will control both the bounds and the days of week, and there are fewer Saturdays and Sundays than weekdays, so you will need a shorter array.

Edit: In my code below I have assumed that the user must pick a Saturday or Sunday within a time range from 1 year 6 months ago till 1 month into the future. I trust you to set the right bounds for you.

### Modern solution

```
    // start 1 year 6 months before today
    // please change to the number of years, months, weeks and/or days you require
    ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusYears(1).minusMonths(6);
    // end 1 month after today - also change to your own requirements
    ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusMonths(1);

    List<Calendar> satsAndSuns = new ArrayList<>(200);
    ZonedDateTime current = start;
    if (current.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
        satsAndSuns.add(GregorianCalendar.from(current));
    }
    current = current.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
    while (! current.isAfter(end)) {
        satsAndSuns.add(GregorianCalendar.from(current));
        // add 1 day to get Sunday
        current = current.plusDays(1);
        assert current.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
        if (current.isAfter(end)) {
            break;
        }
        satsAndSuns.add(GregorianCalendar.from(current));
        // add 6 days to get Saturday
        current = current.plusDays(6);
        assert current.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY);
    }
    Calendar[] selecatbleDays = satsAndSuns.toArray(new Calendar[satsAndSuns.size()]);
```

Edit: I have used `GregorianCalendar.from(current)` for converting from `ZonedDateTime` to the `Calendar` object that MaterialDateTimePicker needs. This method does not exist on Android. According to [the docs](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) and with thanks to Basil Bourque you should instead use `DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(current)`.

Running the above snippet on my computer today produced an array of 165 `Calendar` objects, all Saturdays and Sundays.

### Oldfashioned solution

Use this solution if you do not want to depend on ThreeTen ABP. The algorithm to use is the same as above, only the details are different:

```
    Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
    end.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

    List<Calendar> satsAndSuns = new ArrayList<>(200);
    // start 1 year 6 months before today
    Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
    current.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    current.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
    if (current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        // we need to add a copy because we will continue to modify current
        // I really don’t like using clone(), but it’s the simplest way
        satsAndSuns.add((Calendar) current.clone());
    }
    // Set current to next saturday
    // This is where Calendar is not so straightforward as ZonedDateTime
    // Subtraction of day of week works because in Calendar, Saturday is the last day of the week
    current.add(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.SATURDAY - current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    assert current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY;
    while (! current.after(end)) {
        satsAndSuns.add((Calendar) current.clone());
        current.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        assert current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY;
        if (current.after(end)) {
            break;
        }
        satsAndSuns.add((Calendar) current.clone());
        current.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        assert current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY;
    }
    Calendar[] selecatbleDays = satsAndSuns.toArray(new Calendar[satsAndSuns.size()]);
```

### `.equals()` or `==` with enums?

Edit: It’s not really part of the question, but now we came to debate it: I had first used `current.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY` because I find it a bit simpler to read than `.equals()`. It works because `DayOfWeek` is an enum and the JVM guarantees there is only one instance of each enum constant. Please find the objections in the comments. Basil Bourque has a point in teaching young programmers first and foremost to use `.equals()` for comparing objects for identity. Many have used long hours searching for a bug caused by using `==` between strings or other objects.

Comment: One of the Best explained solutions i have ever come through! Thanks bro @Ole V.V

Comment: Bad habit to be using `==` with objects. Change to `.equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY )`.

Comment: With enums that “bad habit” is all over the project team I’m in. To us it’s a conscious decision, though we are well aware that it is frowned upon in some other places. @BasilBourque

Comment: @Ole V.V. Hi Ole, your solution works great! But instead of setting future saturday instance how can i disable the weekdays in past also...

Comment: As for converting in the back-port, use [`DateTimeUtils`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html). Call [`toGregorianCalendar`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html#toGregorianCalendar-org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime-)

Comment: @ChennaiAugments, to allow picking Saturdays and Sundays in the past, you need to subtract from `start`. Modern example: `start = start.minusYears(1).minusMonths(6);` Old school example: `current.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1); current.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);`.

Comment: Exactly what i have been looking for! Nicely explained guys!

Comment: @OleV.V. Can u please make the change in the code for enabling past weekends. Its not working for me mate

Comment: Yes @OleV.V. Its disabling the Mondays and Sundays. Can you pls make change in the code for disabling in past also

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes can u please make change in code for disabling in Past also, so that we can gain some knowledge in this!

Comment: @ChennaiAugments “Its disabling the Mondays and Sundays.” Or enabling? Sounds like a time zone problem to me. Does it help if you use (modern) `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` or (old) `Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`?

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your knowledge sharing bro. Upon testing, your code works great ! One observance is that when the calendar instance day is a Saturday, then next week's saturday and sunday is being disabled. That's the only flaw i encountered

Comment: If that’s a problem, I can look into it if you explain with more details. Which of the `Calendar` instances? Also tell me whether you are using `setDisabledDays()` or `setSelectableDays()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.Monday` is just a constant for an `int` not a `Calendar` object.

From the Calendar implementation:

```
/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;
```